# multi viewcontroller and full screen

Tags: iphone

I have a project in which I prefer only display full screen mode in one viewcontroller's view.
I used `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES]` to hide the status bar in the sub view controller.

The time display and battery icon disappeared, but there is a blank  white block replaced statusbar.

I sticked on it for 2 days, still can not solve.

Welcome any comment.

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that means that you have to resize/reposition your view to start in 0,0 instead of 0,20.

Comment: Thanks，I used CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,320f,480.f)